# Finding specific value within a loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, combobox, enums, iteration

I'm using an Enum within a `ComboBox`. I want it to allow editing, so that the user can type things in it. I converted the Enum to a `string[] arrayItems` while `listItems` is the length of the Enum list.

Now I want to check the users text input: If it isn't listed, it should show a message that the item is not listed there.

But for my code (below) it shows me a error multiple times:

```
// Converted enum to string[] before

for (int i = 0; i < listItems; i++)
{
    if (comboBox1.Text != arrayItems[i])
    {
        message = string.Format("Sorry! " + comboBox1.Text + " not found.");
    }
}
```

This shows error every time I start it as it iterates through each and every element in the list. I want that if this could check the whole Enum list and give the error once in case of wrong input.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your loop as

```
bool ok = false;
for (int i = 0; i < listItems; i++)
{
    if (comboBox1.Text == arrayItems[i])
    {
        ok=true;
        break;
    }
}

if(ok==false)
{
    message = string.Format("Sorry! " + comboBox1.Text + " not found.");
}
```

Comment: I swear I had not seen your code before posting my example with the same name for the boolean variable :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(arrayItrmd.Contains(combobox1.Text))
{
    //logic if trur
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ's [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this. As the name implies, it will only be true if all elements correspond to your query. It's basically the equivalent of `!Any`

```
if (arrayItrmd.All(item => item != comboBox1.Text))
{
    message = string.Format("Sorry! " + comboBox1.Text + " not found.");
}
```

This means "If each element from arrayItrmd is not equal to comboBox1's text, assign the message."

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the use of a loop

```
if(tmpImageArray.FirstOrDefault(a => a == comboBox1.Text) == default(String))
{
   message = comboBox1.Text + " not found";
}
else{
   message = comboBox1.Text + " found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem like this,

First my enum that I will bind to my combobox

```
 public enum comboboxVals
    {
        one, two, three
    }
```

Then set my combobox's datasource like this

```
  comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(comboboxVals));
```

and then implemented code in one of my combobox events to check if the value is valid like combobox Leave, Validating and Validated events..

```
 private void comboBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            var cbx = sender as ComboBox;
            if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(comboboxVals), cbx.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(cbx.Text + " not in the list");
                e.Cancel=true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Implement your logic here
            }


        }
```